# RabbitMQ Implementation - Rabbit.erl does not implement start_phase callback function

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I am new to Erlang and RabbitMQ. As I understand a module with behaviour "application" should implement all callbacks functions. In case of rabbit.erl I don't find start_phase implemented in rabbit.erl. I am sure I am missing something .. Thanks in advance for your help in explaining.

Also are there resources where rabbitmq code structure is explained?

Comment: There is no callback star_phase in [application behaviour](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html). There is only `start/2` and `stop/1`.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html for application module where it mentions start_phase as a callback function in the application callback module.

Comment: Right, good to know. It is only used when there are defined phases in [application options](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/application.erl#L49), you shouldn't bother with that. Behaviours are not as "clean" as interfaces in java. Maybe my [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920362/writing-and-compiling-custom-behaviours-in-erlang/27921345#27921345) will help you.

Comment: I wonder why you want to know about RabbitMQ internal architecture? Also take a look at this repo: https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbit-internals/blob/master/rabbit_boot_process.md and this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/old_sound/dissecting-the-rabbit and http://vimeo.com/98429656